# How i use array of vector3 to list in inspector all vector3 in list?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

In the top of script:

```
public Vector3[] positionsList;
List<Vector3> positions = new List<Vector3>();
```

In Update: I'm updating the List but i also want to update the array so i can watch the vector3 positions in the inspector while the game is running.

```
var position = GenerateRandomPositions(objects[0]);

        if (!positions.Contains(position))
        {
             positions.Add(position);
        }
```

Comment: What's your question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply make the List public, the inspector can handle it.

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class ListInInspectorTest : MonoBehaviour {

    public List<Vector3> superawesomeListOfVector3s;

    void Update () {

        if(superawesomeListOfVector3s.Count < 10) {
            superawesomeListOfVector3s.Add(Random.insideUnitSphere);
        }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If it is important that the variable is private or protected to other code. you could add the [SerializeField] tag above the variable that you want to see in the inspector. source (https://unity3d.com/learn/tutorials/topics/tips/show-private-variables-inspector)